# Sokobunny I (Sokoban, but the boxes are sentient)

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, maze

## Sokobunny 1

**You *love* buns!**
You love them so much, that you chased one down a bunburrow. The burrows are like mazes, and **YOU WANT TO CATCH THE FLUFFBALLS!!!!** However, the buns are smart! You can't catch the bun by by chasing after it, as you *wait out of politeness for the buns*.

Taken from the game `Paquerette Down the Bunburrows` (This is imo easily the best puzzle game out there, as it is ***meta*** **meta** *meta* *meta* ... *echoes until inaudible*)

### Bun behavior

- Buns will run straight away from you if they can, until they reach a tile with a non-wall left or right. It they see no exits, they run straight ahead.
- A bun is comfortable until you are closer than two squares (manhattan), this means a bun will keep a distance of two empty squares horizontally and vertically, but won't care about diagonals.
- A bun won't choose to go into a dead end it can see.
- A bun can see horizontally and vertically and and tell if it is a straight dead end.
- A bun can see all adjacent squares (horiz, vert, and diag)
- A bun will prefer to turn left, if given the choice.
- A bun is captured if on the same tile as a player.

### Challenge:

Shortest wins!

- Global guarantees: No buns will ever be harmed in the making of these challenges.
- Guarantees (this challenge only):

  - no bun will be captured
  - no bun will  run out of bounds
  - mazes will always be a rectangle
- Inputs:

  - Ascii Maze: `#` is a wall, and   is not
  - Player position. (Col, row), starting from top-left at (0, 0)
  - Bunny position. Same scheme
- Outputs:

  - New bunny position
  - All rotated inputs should output the same relative position
- You must treat any non `#` character as a wall. This applies expressly to the `P` and `B` characters.

the bun after it moves (if it does).

````
Visual representation (Not valid for challenge):
B is bun, b is where bun goes.
███████████████████████████████████████
████████████████████████   ███   ██████
█████████████████████               ███
██████████████████████████████   ██████
██████          P     B------->b    ███
████████████   ████████████████████████
███████████████████████████████████████

Maze:
#############
######## # ##
#######     #
########## ##
##   P B    #
#### ########
#############
Player: (5, 4)
Bun:    (7, 4)

Output: (10, 4)

Maze:
#############
######## # ##
#######     #
########## ##
##      P B #
#### ########
#############
Player: (8, 4)
Bun:    (10, 4)

Output: (10, 2)

Maze:
############################
#P B                       #
######################### ##
############################
Player: (1, 1)
Bun:    (3, 1)

Output: (25,1)

Maze:
######
### ##
#P B##
###  #
######
Player: (1, 2)
Bun:    (3, 2)

Output: (3, 3)

Maze:
#######
###  ##
## B###
##  ###
###P###
#######
Player: (3, 4)
Bun:    (3, 2)

Output: (2, 2)

Maze:
#######
#P  B #
#######

Player: (1, 1)
Bun:    (4, 1)

Output: (4, 1)

Maze:
#######
# P B #
#######

Player: (2, 1)
Bun:    (4, 1)

Output: (5, 1)

Maze:
#######
#  PB #
#######

Player: (3, 1)
Bun:    (4, 1)

Output: (5, 1)
```
````

Comment: "A bun will prefer to turn left, if given the choice" I assume that, since we do not know which way they are facing, this means they prefer West, South, East, and finally North on the input map? (Doesn't that invalidate the "All rotated inputs should output the same relative position" bit though?)

Comment: Someone should answer this in [JavaScript (Bun)](https://bun.sh)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I think it's left relative to the direction away from you.

Comment: Correct @xnor. The bun will always face away from you before it starts running. Then you know which direction its facing.

Comment: Could you clarify what is an intersection for "Buns will run straight away from you if they can, until they reach an intersection."?

Comment: Can input be, say, a 0-1 matrix instead of ascii?

Comment: Consider maze 2 in the test cases, where the bun goes to 25,1.  Now assume the game continues until the player is within 2 squares again.  The bun is trapped either way, but does the bun move forward or to the right, or does it not matter?  Or does the bun not move at all because both are dead ends?

Comment: "A bun is comfortable until you are closer than two squares (manhattan)" It seems like being exactly 2 squares from you in a straight line causes the bun to run? Does this apply if the bun is diagonally 1 space away from you? What happens then?

Comment: Ok, a bun won't move when you are next to it diagonally, because a diagonal is manhattan distance 2 @xnor

Comment: @Jonah the bun runs away from you, straight ahead.

Comment: I'm voting to close as there's lacking clarity behind the distance a bun is comfortable for. I'll rescind my vote if this is clarified. (Perhaps provide a diagram of 'threatening' spaces?)

Comment: Could you please also clarify if not being comfortable is a condition for the bun to start running, a condition for it to continue running, or both? Also, does a bun with no escape squares presumably stay still?

Comment: Hmm…maybe we can add the meta-nonsense in a future version.

Comment: Why `Maze:
#######
###  ##
## B###
##  ###
###P###
#######
Player: (3, 4)
Bun:    (3, 2)

Output: (2, 2)`?

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, 791 bytes:

```py
M=[(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(-1,0)]
def F(b,x,y,X,Y,s):
 q,s=[(X,Y)],s+[(X,Y)]
 while q:
  X,Y=q.pop(0)
  for J,K in M:
   if(U:=(X+J,Y+K))not in s and' '==b[X+J][Y+K]:yield(*U,(J,K));q+=[U];s+=[U]
def f(b,c,C):
 (y,x),(Y,X)=c,C
 q=[(X,Y,*([(0,-1),(0,1)][y<Y]if x==X else[(-1,0),(1,0)][x<X]),[])]
 while q:
  X,Y,j,k,s=q.pop(0);P=abs(x-X)+abs(y-Y)>2
  T=[((J,K),any(B!=(J,K)for B in F(b,x,y,X+J,Y+K,[(X,Y)])))for J,K in M if(X+J,Y+K)not in s and' '==b[X+J][Y+K] and abs(x-X)+abs(y-Y)<abs(x-X-J)+abs(y-Y-K)]
  T=[(a,b)for a,b in T if b or not any(B for _,B in T)]
  if[]==T or (len(T)==1 and not T[0][1]and P):return(X,Y)
  if any(i[0]!=(j,k)for i in T)and P:return(X,Y)
  if(K:=[(0,j),(-1*k,0)][k!=0])in[i[0]for i in T]and P:return(X+K[0],Y+K[1])
  for(J,K),_ in T:q+=[(X+J,Y+K,J,K,s+[(X+J,Y+K)])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTbbuJADH1evsJtHpgBU3HrRbSzD11pH4q6QiqVQLOjCpZETYsSSFIt@XrWngkpt1Z92CAxsX3sY5@xssiz5zjqXC2S9fpeadHElkT6b/DRwib9N/gwlZkfwE8xxRXmOMIxprJXgSWmlESmNJjWi7cK/H0O5z4sCQDkUcuzRbwQTUlmECdwh30II7jnMISBeOwpMarf4bjelzKKMw6mMIlmVagqNdUUM5qCppeH/nwmao8oqIaU18u60o/mOrWH7TCgDv/gD@5N5Lii9sc4kopc1KxrFWtCbybkcY3Ob8YmDGCl1Aj8eeprN7MTwOjVzchI1OZwMnzBV1JgM9/1QE2mqVg1RrLOL3ljLL@3CTokZtsyTqJc3J4oa7AWtzxsKasTAQsdpZTbcrFUG5k@U4l9cNDHTeFp3JW@Rp8nss1NcGq56OS6Q@KCKZCDiWzP9uae0PY7tHlhoI1SQ0aJuR@JoVSqZck5aaibRrcMmwPZS/zsLYnsWDbT1gwJQlKQhpY7dKVtxkGC6Pfsdr7Yhay92ot5PVFNI8NIc6X3Ema3RL1PUVaN2ilW0N3Fk0X3eIk2wiIF3CIXQtOlr3mvsvhpGk@SmXig1frmSmtdC99pg3Ce@Yn4FUc@wsNZupiHmaj@jqqS1EpboOD09LTibT@lBfQrLeDH20K6GDkHtC5lDA6qOItZ0vb/oCsYv0DXOUa391S8ov0jj/dxJnje52VtA92dBiqbPGIsrJLC4c93Gy4gdu5br5i/8A@2ZnbJF/vJAyhlKkGX@6AtLUvQ1QEIBvugRRJGmQhEuYEpf7jOEbp0XPIh5RFQm6JXDtRqfojq2I8ccMUOH0dBXQdqO1D7OOjcRbufgi7e6bof0l1StP0VUGcHtP4H)

Comment: You can save 5 bytes from indentation, by condensing variable declarations, lines 9-10 can be made into one, and 12-14 can be condensed. Eg. `T=...` and `T=...` can be `T=...;T=...`